# SQL analytics endpoint and Semantic model not being created in MS Fabric Lakehouse

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-fabric, data-lakehouse

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-engineering/tutorial-build-lakehouse) article to create a Power BI report from Fabric enabled workspace. I've tried this in both Free trial and have one premium fabric capacity. I believe after Lakehouse is created it should add default SQL Analytics endpoint and Semantic model after I upload a csv file with **New Dataflow Gen2**.
But this doesn't happen. Also, the button to add *New Semantic Model* manually is disabled for me. See below image for reference.

[image: New Semantic Model disabled and Retry not working]

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hello, please add print screen of your workspace, you should be able to view lakehouse, and two childs - sql end point and default semantic model, if none, try to create new lakehouse from workspace screen